# My google app instances does not seem to be on correct region

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, ip-geolocation, google-cloud-networking

I have just created one google app engine application and one 2nd Generation MySQL instance in **eu-west2** region. In GCP Console they both seems to be in eu-west2 region.

However when I try to gelocate my ip's they seem to be in somewhere in US.

**What should I do to use GCP in eu-west2 region?**

*my GCP instances:*

[image]
[image]

*their locations:*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

Google has an extensive world wide network. What you are seeing is us routing you to Google's closest Point of Presence ([POP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_presence)), which from that point on you're on a software defined network ([SDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking)). What this means is we get your traffic on to our fast network as quickly as possible and abstract away the details of getting you to the machine in question.

Check latency from you to these hosts, then spin up a VM in Europe and check latency from that VM to these hosts - you'll find the numbers will confirm they really are in eu-west2.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I already have the same app deployed in us-central region. Latency tests also show they are in same location independent from region setting.  I have tested with 2 VMs(one in us, one in uk) and with ping command. latency doesnt changed in each VM per app.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I am having the same problem. We have strict client guidelines which says that there should be no trace that the request is goes out of europe region. I have the GAE GMysql instance running into the europe region but when I am trying to do ip address lookup it always shows that the ip is based in US not europe. 
What is the solution we can have so that we the ip address lookup shows its based in Europe not in US. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, you can find more about it here: [Outgoing HTTP Request Location on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108523/outgoing-http-request-location-on-google-app-engine)

Is about the Google Network usage, the outgoing traffic come from the "Point of Presence" instead of the location and it can be dynamic. In my case, I have no solution, since it's mandatory to my API to make the requests from Brazil =\