# Why do regional Google Cloud IP addresses all appear to be in the US?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a VM in the asia-east1 region. It gets an IP address of 35.201.212.242. When I look up this IP address on services like iplocation.net, I'm told it is in the US.

The same is true of a VM I created in the australia-southeast1 region. IP is 35.197.162.146.

Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever)

Comment: Same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829340/my-google-app-instances-does-not-seem-to-be-on-correct-region

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I dont think google cloud has a solution for it yet. :(

For details : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112448138

And I think AWS is better in this case it shows the correct location:
[Created GCE in europe region but IP address shows its in US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801691/created-gce-in-europe-region-but-ip-address-shows-its-in-us)