# Firebase Cloud Functions: Scraping function runs on US server although different region is set

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is subscribed to messages of a pubsub topic and scrapes the given url (which is part of the message) using puppeteer. I set the region to `europe-west3` (my firebase project is based in this region as well) since I want to make sure that scraping is done on a server in this region (scraping the url from the US will yield different results). However, judging from the scraping output, the function is **still run on a US server.**

The [Cloud Functions location documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) seems to imply that by setting the region I can determine the location where a given function runs.

I have also gone into the Firebase Console for my project and verified that the functions have the correct location.

Am I missing something here? Is it possible to specify the region where my web scraping logic should be executed?

```
exports.updateDocWithScrapingData = functions.runWith({ memory: '1GB', timeoutSeconds: 120 }).region('europe-west3').pubsub.topic('myTopic').onPublish(async (message) => {
    const urlMap = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString());
    // Scraping is done using puppeteer in separate file
    const scrapedData = await scraper.fetchData(urlMap['url']);
    const docId = urlMap['id'];
    const refDoc = db.collection('myCollection').doc(docId);
    const doc = await refDoc.get();
    if (doc.exists) {
        // Update doc using scrapedData
    } else {
        // Create doc using scrapedData
    }
    return {
        response: 'Success',
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

This is my scraping function in scraper.js:

```
const fetchData = async (url) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

    const games = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const gamesArr = Array.from(document.querySelector('.grid-wrapper').querySelectorAll('.grid-event-wrapper'));
        return gamesArr.map(game => game.innerText);
    });

    await browser.close();
    console.log(games);
    return games;
}
```

This is an example url I am trying to scrape: https://sports.bwin.de/de/sports/basketball-7/wetten/nordamerika-9/nba-6004

Expected output for `europe-west3` (Function should be running in Frankfurt, Germany):

```
['Chicago Bulls
@
Indiana Pacers
Morgen / 01:05
KON…95
-5,5
1.87
▲ 224,5
1.91
▼ 224,5
1.91
2.85
1.44', 'Brooklyn Nets
@
Sacramento Kings
Morgen / 04:05
K…87
+3,5
1.95
▲ 242,5
1.87
▼ 242,5
1.95
1.57
2.45']
```

This is the actual output from the cloud function:

```
['Chicago Bulls
@
Indiana Pacers
Morgen / 01:05
KON…05
-5,5
-115
▲ 224,5
-110
▼ 224,5
-110
+185
-225', 'Brooklyn Nets
@
Sacramento Kings
Morgen / 04:05
K…15
+3,5
-105
▲ 242,5
-115
▼ 242,5
-105
-175
+145']
```

Notice the difference between the betting odds. US uses Money Line whereas in Germany for example you simply get the odds as a multiple of 1.

Comment: Hi there, can you please share the output of scrapping that tells you that the function is running on a us server?

Comment: Hi Antonio, I added some example output.

Comment: Thank you, I think the issue is with the default geolocation that the headless browser is using within the Google Cloud Function. I have run some tests to obtain the ip address of some of my CFs and then resolved them which always resulted in location = california. I see that with puppetter you can set geolocation. Have you already tried it? https://chercher.tech/puppeteer/geo-locations-puppeteer

Comment: Thanks for your help, Antonio, but setting the geolocation does not solve this issue. I guess my problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801691/created-gce-in-europe-region-but-ip-address-shows-its-in-us) and cannot be solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801691/created-gce-in-europe-region-but-ip-address-shows-its-in-us) exactly describes the reason why you are obtaining values from US servers.

```
All the IP addresses Google provides to GCP user are registered with ARIN
under the Google HQ in Mountain View, California (in other words SWIP to be
Mountain View, CA). So, all geolocations lookup of the IP addresses will 
resolve to the United States even though the actual server is located 
somewhere else. In addition to that, in GCP, it's not uncommon to remap a 
block of IPs from one location to another, especially given the elasticity of 
IP addresses for the GCP and they way they are recycled or reused.
```