# Google Cloud - Region for the server when "pinging" is wrong - Its for game server

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

I have a dedicated Linux server running a game. I can connect all good but when I go to websites that shows servers it says my server is in the US when its hosted in Belgium. I need this to change as it won't show up for the EU people. The ip of the server is currently `104.199.110.137`. If you use ip location tool it shows it's in the US but it's not!

Some links to the websites showing wrong region:
https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/rust/6586906

Comment: You need to ask your hosting service what "hosted in Belgium" means, because the IP address is clearly a number in the americas (ARIN) assigned to Google Cloud. This is probably something you cannot fix via a web-based self-service interface.

Comment: You cannot use geolocation with Google Global IP addresses. They can be anywhere in the world simultaneously. The address that you see is the registered business address and not the data center(s) that the address is `currently` being used at. Look at Anycast Addressing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Anycast_addressing and Border Gateway Protocol which routes the address to the closed data center.

Comment: This topic has been already discussed and answered many times over the past few years: [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gce-discussion/RjzyHRBRujg), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46205814), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41988170), 
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44829340), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51801691), [6](https://serverfault.com/q/995974), [7](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112448138). This question looks duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever)